# I want find duplicated values in my excel sheet and change the text colors in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I want find duplicated values in my excel sheet and change the text colors in c#
with this code:

```
            Excel.Application xlApp =
            new Excel.Application();
            //xlApp.Visible = true;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(DtaSource1);
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
        
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            for(int k=1;k<=rowCount;k++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
                {

                    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                    {

                        if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j] == xlRange.Cells[k, 1])
                        {
                            xlRange.Cells[i, j].value = "00000";
                            xlWorksheet.SaveAs(DtaSource1);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

but it's does not working and when i want to save changes it's throw out the error excel sheet read- only!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of [highlight duplicate and unique values in Excel](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Conditional-Formatting/Highlight-Duplicate-and-Unique-Values-in-Excel-Using-C.html) by using Spire.XLS, maybe you can have a try.

```
//Load the Excel file
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile("Input.xlsx");

//Get the first worksheet
Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

//Use conditional formatting to highlight duplicate values in range "A2:A10" with IndianRed color
ConditionalFormatWrapper format1 = sheet.Range["A2:A10"].ConditionalFormats.AddCondition();
format1.FormatType = ConditionalFormatType.DuplicateValues;
format1.BackColor = Color.IndianRed;

//Save the file            
workbook.SaveToFile("HighlightDuplicates.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2013);
```